# TypeError: instances.map is not a function angular loopback

Tags: angular, typescript, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I'm using the  @mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder  to generate my api on angular 4.3.6 and i am getting an error when i use this call

```
this._userApi.findUsersByRoles([{'name':'cliente'}]).subscribe((users: User[]) => {
  this.users = users;
}, (err) => {console.log(err) })
```

When i try this method in the loopback explorer i am getting an array of users.

[debug capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWhoO.png)

This is the 'findUsersByRoles' function generated by the loopback sdk

```
  public findUsersByRoles(roles: any, customHeaders?: Function): Observable<User[]> {
    let _method: string = "GET";
    let _url: string = LoopBackConfig.getPath() + "/" + LoopBackConfig.getApiVersion() +
    "/users/findUserByRoles";
    let _routeParams: any = {};
    let _postBody: any = {};
    let _urlParams: any = {};
    if (typeof roles !== 'undefined' && roles !== null) _urlParams.roles = roles;
    let result = this.request(_method, _url, _routeParams, _urlParams, _postBody, null, customHeaders);
    return result.map((instances: Array<User>) =>
        instances.map((instance: User) => new User(instance))
    );
  }
```

And this is the printed error in the console :

[Capture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agVsF.png)

I suspect that this could be a bug in the sdk builder, since the angular project is recent and has not had many changes in the overall structure.

**Solution**

As I have been told in the answers, the problem is that instances is not an array, to fix this i had to set the property root : true on the remoteMethod definition in the loopback model

```
returns: {
        arg: 'users',
        type: 'array',
        root : true
      }
```

Comment: "i am getting an array of users" are you sure? What does `console.log(instances)` print inside `result.map` ?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment but I don't think typeof `instances` is `Array<User>`

Comment: i updated showing the value of intances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instances` is an object, as you see in the debug capture. It has the property `users` which is an array. So you need to call the map function on the `users` array.

```
instances.users.map((instance: User) => new User(instance));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you are calling `map` on the variable which is not an array, make sure to console log `instances` variable to see if it really contains an array.The error is telling you that `map` is not a function because your variable is not any array and `map` is array function in this context.

Comment: i added a debug capture showing the value of instances

Comment: You see in the console that instances is an object which contains the array of users, so you should try `instances.users.map` instead of `instances.map`